# Ghost4J. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gsdll64'

Tags: java, ghostscript, jvm-arguments, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I included `Ghost4J 0.45` into my project using Maven and  installed Ghostscript into `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.06`.

But I still get an error  `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gsdll64'`.

I added into `PATH` env variable directory where located  'gsdll64.dll' (i.e. `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.06`). Also tried launch application using `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir`.

But I alwways get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` (but when I launch using JVM argument `-Djava.library.path` I get `ClassNotFound` exception (Eclipse can't find Main class, but I manually point Eclipse to Main class when I laucnh my app))/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it work if you copy `gsdll64` to your working directory? :-)

Answer (score 1):

if u want to use a system property 
`-Djna.library.path=/path/to/dir` should be used instead of  `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir`