# Where I should place gsdll64.dll in host with windows7 and tomcat7?

Tags: java, windows-7, tomcat7, ghostscript

I use [`ghost4j GhostScript`](http://www.ghost4j.org/) to manage TIFF and PDF files in a webapp. 
I included `Ghost4J` into my project using `Maven` and installed `Ghostscript` into `C:\Program Files\gs\...` but after this I still get an error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gsdll64'

To solve this, I must place the file `gsdll64.dll` in working directory (usually `c:\eclipse`) as [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153235/ghost4j-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-unable-to-load-library-gsdll64).

Till here everything fine, but when I deploy the app in the integration environment (`win7` and `tomcat7`) I get this exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.**NoClassDefFoundError**: **Could not initialize class org.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibrary**.

I installed `Ghostscript` into `C:\Program Files\gs\...` in the host and as in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325579/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-xxx) I wrapped code with `try {} catch (Exception e)` but does not seem to help.

Any idea where I should place the `gsdll64.dll` or how to solve the error?

Comment: Have you tried placing the dll in C:\Windows\System32?

Comment: @TT. same error... :(

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (if it exists)? Sorry for guessing =)

Comment: @TT. nope again... sig!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add dll to `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/bin` as it is usually on the PATH.

Alternatively add the directory that contains the dll to PATH since on Windows, `java.library.path` is initialised from the PATH environment variable.

Check [this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038789/default-java-library-path) for reference.

For Tomcat 7, can copy `gsdll64.dll` to `%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin` directory or create `setenv.bat` under `%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin` directory with the following entry.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\gs\gs9.18\bin
```

where `C:\gs\gs9.18` is the installed Ghostscript folder. Check Apache Tomcat Native Library installation document on this.

Comment: This answer makes sense, but actually I already tried both options without success... there is something basic I'm missing for sure... but I'm blind now...

Comment: I downloaded Ghost4j source from github, running "mvn test" gets the UnsatisfiedLinkError error. After copying gsdll64.dll to %JAVA_HOME%/jre/bin, that error went away. My JAVA_HOME is set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66" and has %JAVA_HOME%/bin added to the beginning of Path under System Variables.Could be that your java is running from "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin" instead of "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\bin".

Comment: If you read my question, you will see I do this without problem in the development environment, but my problem is in the integration, where host and client machines are different (what should not affect...) and error is also different `NoClassDefFound`....

Comment: Somehow missed Tomcat7 part. Place gsdll64.dll under Tomcat/bin folder and it should be able to load properly.